# Combine dataframe excluding redundant columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes, one with 56 528 obs. for 18 variables, and one with 56 528 obs. for 45 variables. The observations are in the same 'order' since those dataframe are a subset of an original dataset. 8 variables of my first dataframe are  absent in my second dataframe, and I want to add the columns from the first dataframe that are missing in the second, without having to write the names of these columns one by one. I would like a generalizable function.

I read that merge (dataframe1, dataframe2) is supposed to do the job. In my case, it gives me a dataframe with 1 372 978 obs. for 53 variables. The number of variables looks ok, but I don't know what happened with the rows... Any recommandations ?

Here an example :

```
data(nhanes) #25 obs. 4 var.

i<-subset(nhanes,select=c(bmi,hyp)) #df1 with two variables from nhanes, 25 obs. 2 var.

nhanes_m<-subset(nhanes, select=c(age,bmi,chl)) #df2 with three variables from nhanes, 25 obs. 3 var.
```

Like in my example, here we have two dataframe, with the same number of observations, in the same order, but not exactly the same columns. If I want to combine df1 and df2, so that I obtain again 25 obs. for 4 variables (the redundant columns are excluded, we just 'bind' the columns that are unique between df1 and df2 to one or the other dataframe), how should I do ?

```
nhanes_f<-merge(nhanes_m,i)  #gives 97 obs. 4 variables, instead of 25 obs. 4 var.
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: If there are duplicates for the `by` columns in `merge`, it would have this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably the names of the columns that the two data frames share will be the same, so just find the names that don't match, subset the data frame by them and `cbind` them together. Here's a reprex:

```r
(df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 11:15, c = 21:25, d = 31:35))
#>   a  b  c  d
#> 1 1 11 21 31
#> 2 2 12 22 32
#> 3 3 13 23 33
#> 4 4 14 24 34
#> 5 5 15 25 35

(df2 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 11:15, e = 21:25, f = 31:35))
#>   a  b  e  f
#> 1 1 11 21 31
#> 2 2 12 22 32
#> 3 3 13 23 33
#> 4 4 14 24 34
#> 5 5 15 25 35

cbind(df1, df2[!(names(df2) %in% names(df1))])
#>   a  b  c  d  e  f
#> 1 1 11 21 31 21 31
#> 2 2 12 22 32 22 32
#> 3 3 13 23 33 23 33
#> 4 4 14 24 34 24 34
#> 5 5 15 25 35 25 35
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks ! I'm not used to that kind of notation (%in%) but I'll start learning it :)

Comment: Do you know why the merge function doesn't work here ?

Comment: I'd guess it's because you haven't merged on all overlapping columns, but difficult to be sure without hands-on data. If the data frames are already matched row-wise, it's more efficient to just bind them like this anyway I think.